# This function has a return type of 'int', but doesn't end with a return statement

Tags: flutter, dart

Warning:

```
This function has a return type of 'int', but doesn't end with a return statement.  Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.
```

I am getting a warning in this code:

```
int _duration = 0;
  int getDuration(String date) {
    //print("Date $date");
    //load the data from firebase and add to the list
    fb.reference()
      ..child(cuser.uid)
          .child('Seizure_history')
          .child(date)
          .once()
          .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.value;
        list = List();
        if (data != null) {
          data.forEach((key, value) {
            EventList seizure_history = new EventList(
              seiz_duration: value['duration'],
              dateTime: value['datetime'],
              key: key,
            );
            list.add(seizure_history);
            setState(() {
              _duration = int.parse(list[list.length - 1].seiz_duration);
            });
            print("Duration $_duration");
            return _duration;
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

I have also returned the duration but it is still showing the warning, please help me out where I am going wrong? It is printing duration correctly on the console but not returning.

I want to return the duration after finding it in firebase but it is still showing zero which means no value is returning, why is it happening. I am new to flutter and I am still learning.

UPDATED:

this function is called inside `initState()`:

```
var series;
  var data;
  //Charts
  getCharts()
  {
    data = [
      addcharts(sevenDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(seven),
          charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
      addcharts(sixDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(six),
          charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
      addcharts(fiveDay.substring(0, 2),getDuration(five),
          charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
      addcharts(fourDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(four),
          charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
      addcharts(threeDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(three),
          charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
      addcharts(twoDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(two),
          charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
      addcharts(oneDay.substring(0, 2), getDuration(one),
          charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(const Color(0xffe8e5af))),
    ];
    series = [
      charts.Series(
        domainFn: (addcharts addcharts, _) => addcharts.weeks,
        measureFn: (addcharts addcharts, _) => addcharts.duration,
        colorFn: (addcharts addcharts, _) => addcharts.barColor,
        id: 'addcharts',
        data: data,
      ),
    ];

  }
```

How can I use the future Builder inside it? That's where i am stuck if i use FutureBuilder

```
Expanded(
                                child: charts.BarChart(
                                  series,
                                  animationDuration: Duration(microseconds: 2000),
                                ),
                              )
```

Comment: You are returning the `Duration` instance inside the `if` block, which is in turn inside a snapshot (`then()`) & then inside a `forEach` loop, better to create a variable with some default duration, update it in the if block & return the same variable or use a callback maybe.

Comment: @DarShan Don't just go for the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should do asynchonous computation inside an asynchoronous method:

```dart
// Return a Future<int> and add async to its declaration
Future<int> getDuration(String date) async {
  final DataSnapshot snapshot = await (fb.reference()
    ..child(cuser.uid)
    .child('Seizure_history')
    .child(date)
    .once());

  var data = snapshot.value;

  // Return a default value in case `snapshot.value` is null
  if (data == null) return 0;

  list = [];
  data.forEach((key, value) {
    final EventList seizure_history = new EventList(
      seiz_duration: value['duration'],
      dateTime: value['datetime'],
      key: key,
    );
    list.add(seizure_history);
    setState(() {
        _duration = int.parse(list[list.length - 1].seiz_duration);
    });
    return _duration;
  });
}
```

However, your logic doesn't make sense. You're trying to return a value (`_duration`) inside a for-each, so there are two possibilities: 1) you want to return the first duration from `data`; or 2) you want to return all the durations from `data`. Here's how you can do in both situations:

1. Returning the first duration from `data`

```dart
Future<int> getDuration(String date) async {
  // ...

  list = [];

  // Get the first entry from data
  var entry = data.first;

  final EventList seizure_history = EventList(
    seiz_duration: entry.value['duration'],
    dateTime: entry.value['datetime'],
    key: entry.key,
  );
  list.add(seizure_history);

  // Get the seizure duration
  final int duration = int.parse(seizure_history.seiz_duration);
  setState(() => _duration = duration);
  return duration;
}
```

2. Returning all the durations from `data`

```
// Since there are multiple durations, use a List<int> instead of int
final List<int> _durations = [];

// Update the method signature
Future<List<int>> getDuration(String date) async {
  // ...

  // Create a local `_durations` to update the property's one only once  
  final List<int> durations = [];

  // Use a map to fetch all the durations
  list = data.map((key, value) {
    final EventList seizure_history = new EventList(
      seiz_duration: value['duration'],
      dateTime: value['datetime'],
      key: key,
    );

    // Add the duration to the local's one
    durations.add(int.parse(seizure_history.seiz_duration);

    // Add the seizure history to the list
    return seizure_history;
  }).toList();

  setState(() => _durations = durations);
  return durations;
}
```

Of course you need to change where are you calling `getDuration` since now it returns a `Future`, but you can use a [`FutureBuilder` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to help you with that.

Comment: Hi! thank you for the solution. But could you help me out how can i implement future builder with flutter_charts, since i'm making a bar chart and i am calling getDuration() function inside where charts are used

Comment: I am getting your point of using FutureBuilder but could you please provide a solution with how can I implement it with charts, i have updated my post

Answer (score -1):

You just have to return an int at the end of your function like so:

```dart
int getDuration(String date) {
    //print("Date $date");
    //load the data from firebase and add to the list
    fb.reference()
      ..child(cuser.uid)
          .child('Seizure_history')
          .child(date)
          .once()
          .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.value;
        list = List();
        if (data != null) {
          data.forEach((key, value) {
            EventList seizure_history = new EventList(
              seiz_duration: value['duration'],
              dateTime: value['datetime'],
              key: key,
            );
            list.add(seizure_history);
            setState(() {
              _duration = int.parse(list[list.length - 1].seiz_duration);
            });
            print("Duration $_duration");
            return _duration;
          });
        }
      });
    return 0;
  }
```

The error comes from the fact that when you defined your function you said that it will return an `int` type, but if the conditions are not fulfilled, it will return nothing (and therefore, don't return an `int`)

Comment: Your answers are wrong because using your code `getDuration` will always return 0, and that's not what OP wanted ("I want to return the duration after finding it in firebase but it is still showing zero").

Answer (score -2):

You also need to return `int` in case your `Future` fails.

```dart
int getDuration(String date) {
  fb.reference(...);
  
  return 0; // Return something here. 
}
```

or

Change your return type to `int?`:

```dart
int? getDuration(String date) {...}
```

Comment: I can't use non nullable language